# Logic of comparision using "in" for tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having trouble in understanding the logic of using "in" for tuples

For instance,

```
t = (0, 2, 2.0, 5.0)
(0) in t gives True #or any single element of t
(0, 2) in t gives False
(0, 2, 2.0) in t gives False

t = [(0, 2, 2.0, 5.0),(0, 1, 0.0, -1.5)]
(0) in t gives False
```

Please kindly enlighten me. Thank you!

Comment: `(0)` is an `int`, not `tuple`.

Comment: Thank you that is correct. But why is (0,2) not in t?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tuple `(0, 2, 2.0, 5.0)` does contain `(0)` because it is just an `int`, `0`.

It does not contain `(0, 2)` because no such tuple is present inside `(0, 2, 2.0, 5.0)`.

Here is an example of a `tuple` that does contain `(0, 2)`:

```
In [3]: (0,2) in ((0,2),)
Out[3]: True
```

Answer (score 1):

As when your search (0) in tuple, it is just searching one single element 0 which is an integer in the tuple.. So it returns True.
When you do a search for (0,2), you are actually searching a tuple inside the tuple which in not present in t, so it returns False in that case. :)

```
In [7]: t = (0, 2, 2.0, 5.0)                                                                                                                                                         

In [8]: (0,2) in t                                                                                                                                                                   
Out[8]: False

In [9]: t = (0, 2, 2.0, 5.0,(0,2))                                                                                                                                                   

In [10]: (0,2) in t                                                                                                                                                                  
Out[10]: True
```